# User deletion: "your votes will be revoked", except when they’re not

Tags: feature-request, voting, help-center, deleted-accounts, wording

The [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) says:

> User deletion is irreversible! By sending this request, your votes will be revoked, and all of your content will be made anonymous.

But this isn’t entirely true. According to [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/323179), if a user has a lot of votes, they may not be reversed. (It’s extremely rare to lose a large number of votes this way, unless the user engaged in voting fraud, or staff did not feel they should be retained.) On Stack Overflow alone, it looks like nearly half a million upvotes were [assigned to Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=topactivity) from deleted users (and we can’t know how many downvotes as those include automatic votes cast by Community itself on low quality content and spam).

The best suggestion I have for wording is to say the "votes *may* be reversed" (if anything needs to be said here) and then explain fully lower on the page.

(This was brought up in the [comments on my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405231/6083675), so I thought it was worth addressing.)

Comment: That’s quite a rare occurrence however, I don’t think the exceptions warrant complicating matters.